# A basic question about direct access to the GPIO registers by the μC units

Tags: microcontroller

Following diagram shows the AVR architecture for Atmega328P from [this source](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/Atmel-7810-Automotive-Microcontrollers-ATmega328P_Datasheet.pdf):
[image]

And below is a simplified diagram for MSP430 micro-controller:

[image]

I'm trying to understand whether these two architectures are very different in one thing.

And that thing is this: If I look at Atmel's diagram I see that the Instruction Registers(CPU registers) have direct access to GPIO registers. But in MSP430 case only the Memory Address have direct access to the GPIO registers.

I thought in all micro-controllers GPIO registers can only be directly accessed through the memory. Am I interpreted something wrong here?

Comment: There is more than one way to draw a diagram. In fact there are zillions of ways. It probably works the same way on both processors, but they drew it differently.

Comment: But do you think the GPIO registers can be directly modified from the CPU registers without using the memory?

Comment: Ultimately all the devices including I/O ports have a memory address (which is itself a register) and not part of internal SRAM; whether a direct register to register transfer is available depends on the addressing modes available within the device.

Comment: These are two very different kinds of diagrams.

Comment: The registers do not have direct access to the I/O any more than the msp430s do.  In either case you can move data between them yes.  You want to write a value to a gpio register from a cpu register, then an instruction will enable the paths along whichever busses are required using some form of bus transaction, be it a simple set of enables or a full bus transaction.   in both cases the gpio registers have an address space that you have to use the right instruction and addressing to access.  how tightly or loosely integrated the cpu core is to the system can vary across designs.

Comment: To give a curious and obscure example of what you seem to be pointing at: some PIC MCUs (older designs with 12-bit instruction format) have a "TRIS" instruction. This instruction modifies the "tristate" flag on GPIO pins. Combine this with a pull-up resistor on the outside, and BAM you've got a way to do I/O without ever touching internal MCU "memory".

Comment: After a quick look around (it is some time since I did AVR assembly) there are a number of instructions that can move data directly to and from the GPIO registers and other internal registers. See https://www.csee.umbc.edu/~alnel1/cmpe311/notes/AVRAddressingModes.pdf

Comment: I don't think it's accurate to say registers "do" *anything*. Registers don't "have access to" anything. Registers don't "want" or "do" anything. They're just registers.

Answer (score 3):

The boxes and arrows in these two diagrams have different meanings; it does not make sense to compare them.

TI's [official MSP430G2553 web site](http://www.ti.com/product/MSP430G2553) shows a functional block diagram that is quite similar to the AVR one:

[image: MSP430G2553 functional block diagram]

And the internals of the CPU also look similar:

[image: MSP430 CPU block diagram]
<sup>(source: [MSP430x2xx Family User's Guide](https://www.ti.com/lit/pdf/slau144))</sup>

Both microcontrollers work in the same way: the CPU and the GPIO module are connected to the address and data buses; when the CPU accesses a memory address in the correct range, the GPIO module acts on that. When writing to the appropriate register (PORTxn on the AVR, PxOUT on the MSP430), the associated port pin changes.